# How to preserve tab state with angular material?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, tabs, angular-material

I am using angular 8 and angular material.
And I have four tabs and in each tab you can do a edit, but if you go back from edit to the tabs, the tab that was lasted selected has to be selected.

I try it like this:

```
export class UIStateService {
  private state: UIState;

  constructor() {}

  setState(state: UIState) {
    this.state = state;
  }

  getState(): UIState {
    return this.state ? this.state : { tabState: 1};
  }
}

export interface UIState {
  tabState: number;
}
```

and in the component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
   const state = this.uiStateService.getState();
   this.setTabState(state.tabState);

  }


  setTabState(tabId: number) {

  }

  getCurrentTabState(): number {

    return 1;
  }
```

and the view looks like this:

```
 <mat-tab-group>
      <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
          <mat-icon class="interviews">speaker_notes</mat-icon>
          <span i18n>Interview reports</span>{{ dossierItemsCountString(itemTypes.Interview) }}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemList; context: { itemType: itemTypes.Interview }"></ng-container>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
          <mat-icon class="notes">note</mat-icon>
          <span i18n>Notes</span>{{ dossierItemsCountString(itemTypes.Note) }}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemList; context: { itemType: itemTypes.Note }"></ng-container>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
          <mat-icon class="goals">grade</mat-icon>
          <span i18n>Goals</span>{{ dossierItemsCountString(itemTypes.Goal) }}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemList; context: { itemType: itemTypes.Goal }"></ng-container>
      </mat-tab>
      <mat-tab>
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
          <mat-icon class="action-steps">list</mat-icon>
          <span i18n>Action steps</span>{{ dossierItemsCountString(itemTypes.ActionStep) }}
        </ng-template>
        <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="itemList; context: { itemType: itemTypes.ActionStep }"></ng-container>
      </mat-tab>
    </mat-tab-group>
```

So what I have to change? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The active tab can be set using the `selectedIndex` attribute of mat-tab-group.

First you need to save default tabState to 0 which points to the first tab. Then, when user changes tab, update the tabState.

```
<mat-tab-group [selectedIndex]="selectedTab"
           (selectedIndexChange)="setTabState($event)">
      ...
</mat-tab-group>
```

Now, fetch the saved state in ngOnInit in your component:

```
export class YourComponent implements ngOnInit {
    selectedTab: number = 0;

    ngOnInit(): void {
       const state = this.uiStateService.getState();
       if (state) {
           this.selectedTab = state.tabState || 0; // Set to 0 if tabState not present
       }
    }

    setTabState(tabId: number): void {
       this.selectedTab = tabId;
       this.uiStateService.setState({tabState: tabId});
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with [selectedIndex]. 
This is property of mat-tab-group.
You can save tab index in one variable and bind it to the selectedIndex property.
Hope this will work.

Comment: I have done that. But and then?    <mat-tab-group #tabGroup [selectedIndex] = "0">

Comment: Are you sure you're setting selectedIndex correctly? Have a look at my answer, that might help.

Comment: If you are using binding syntax i.e. [ ] it will accept variable as a value. In this case you have to pass selectedIndex="0". No [ ].